# How can I use Maven to build a jar with required libraries in a sub-folder (like Eclipse)

Tags: maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

In Eclipse, you can create a project jar with its required dependencies in an adjacent sub-folder by doing ...

1. Export->Java->Runnable JAR file
2. Select Library handling option: Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR

Is there a way to do this with the Maven assembly plugin? Or is there another Maven plugin that would be more appropriate for this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can use assembly plugin.
pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <!-- final name set the jar name, if left it 
    will give defualt "${artifactId}-${version}" -->
    <finalName>jar final name</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <!-- compiler plug in -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- assembly plugin -->
        <!-- the assembly plugin is used to define your 
        final deploy output (jar, zip, dir, war, etc..)-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assembly:package</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- The filename of the assembled distribution 
                        file defualt ${project.build.finalName}-->
                        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <!--    A list of descriptor files path to generate from-->
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- jar plug in -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <!-- to create a class path to your 
                        dependecies you have to fill true in this field-->
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <!-- if you put your dependencySet/outputDirectory 
                        in the assembly file is in a specific folder (lib for example), 
                        you need to add classpathPrefix-->
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>

                        <!-- if you defined your dependencySet/outputFileNameMapping 
                        in the assembly, instead of using the classpathPrefix, 
                        you should use customClasspathLayout, 
                        add the classpathPrefix at the begining of the 
                        customClasspathLayout, and then add the pattern of the outputFileNameMapping, 
                        NOTICE YOU NEED TO ADD '$' BEFOR OF EACH '$'.
                        supported only from version 2.3>-->
                        <!--<classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                        <customClasspathLayout>
                            lib/$${artifact.groupId}.$${artifact.artifactId}.$${artifact.extension}
                        </customClasspathLayout>-->

                    </manifest>

                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

assembly.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly>
    <!--the id will be add to the end of the distribution file -->
    <id>package</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>true</includeBaseDirectory>


    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>target</directory>
            <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>                
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>icons</directory>
            <outputDirectory>icons</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>conf</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <files>
        <!-- you need to create the bat file yourself -->
        <file>
            <source>batFileName.bat</source>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
        </file>
    </files>

        <dependencySets>
            <dependencySet>
                <!--define the outputDirectory of the dependencies, 
                    NOTICE: if it's diffrent from '/'  make sure to 
                    change the classPath configuration for 
                    the maven-jar-plugin in the pom-->
                <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                <!-- maping the dependencies jar names.
                    NOTICE : if you used this definition, you need to use 
                    customClasspathLayout classPath configuration 
                    for the maven-jar-plugin in the pomg-->
                <outputFileNameMapping>
                    ${artifact.groupId}.${artifact.artifactId}.${artifact.extension}
                </outputFileNameMapping>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </dependencySet>
        </dependencySets>

</assembly>
```

Comment: There was a time when we told others to use Maven to get with just a definition and a lot of "convention" the result you want. With Ant (and other build tools as well) it would be a no-brainer ... :-(

Comment: well there are few benefits for maven, you just need to find them? the decision of using maven in our projects isn't mine, so i need to love with it and make my best

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! With a few tweaks, your samples work perfectly for our project. This means we can move the Java build to the build server. That is a huge improvement in our process and application stability. Again, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you want but if you use the `war:war` goal (with `-DfailOnMissingWebXml=false`) it will put the dependencies in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory in your `target` folder.

Alternatively check out the [dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

Comment: Like you said, not exactly what we're looking for but will let us automate the build, so +1! If I don't hear an all-Maven solution soon, you'll definitely get answer credit. Thanks artbristol!