# How can I create an executable jar with dependencies in sub folder in jar using Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

How can I create an executable jar with dependencies in sub folder in jar using Maven?

The following pom.xml will make a executable jar with the dependencies in the root but what if I wanted all the dependencies in a sub-folder in the jar so its easy if someone else would want to look in the jar.  How can I change the following pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>DRBP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DRBP</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <springframework-version>3.2.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
-->

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
            </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400-full</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>DRBP</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attached</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>org.xxxx.batch.MainBatch</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. A jar is not supposed to contain other jars. A special class loader is needed to be able to use such a jar, and it causes more problems than it solves. If you want to be able to deliver a single artifact, the zip the jars.

Comment: can you point me to example

Comment: An example of what? A zip file containing jar files?

Comment: no how I can make maven do all the work to build it all

Comment: @JBNizet I think its pretty clear he wants a single executable Jar like many projects such has jenkins and solr do. So yeah he wants a special class loader.

Comment: No, I don't have such an example, sorry.

Comment: You need to explain what requirements you have that require you to do something so unorthodox and seemingly wrong.

Comment: It is not so easy. A detailed answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758099/how-can-i-use-maven-to-build-a-jar-with-required-libraries-in-a-sub-folder-like

Comment: @djechlin there is nothing wrong about this question. Many people want "fat jars". See DropWizard.

Comment: @djechlin I think DropWizard like I said before makes it very clear why its nice: http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/#building-fat-jars . Personally I think its nice also and there are several projects that do this like Solr, and Jenkins. All you have to do to run it is `java -jar nameofjar.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [**Maven Shade**](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin.

If you want a full web app in a single jar there are a couple of options:

- Do what [DropWizard](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/getting-started/#building-fat-jars) does which is an example maven shade + jetty.
- The [Tomcat version +2 Maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/executable-war-jar.html)
- [Winstone](http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#embedding)

Comment: You beat me to it.  +1 for Maven Shade.